# Is the Barometric Pressure from the Here Destination Weather API MSLP corrected?

Tags: here-api

Is the barometerPressure that is returned by the HERE Destination Weather API corrected to mean sea-level pressure (MSLP)?

The description that is given doesn't seem to indicate if this is a corrected or uncorrected value.

> Barometric pressure in mbar/in.
> If the element is in the response and it contains a value, there is a Double in the String. If the element is in the response and it does not contain a value, there is an asterisk (*) in the String.